# Rendered Component doesn't show in storybook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js, storybook

I want to render MUI Button Component in my storybook and then change MUI attributes(variant, color, disabled, etc.) from storybook. I could get result when working on simple plain html button but it doesn't work on MUI one. The current result is it doesn't show any error in terminal, nor in browser. When I type something in *args* it's visible on Storybook Controls but Button itself doesn't show up itself. Here is the code of *MyNewButton.tsx* file.

```
import Button from "@mui/material/Button"
export const MyNewButton = () => {
  return <Button />
}
```

and here is the code of *MyNewButton.stories.tsx*

```
import { ComponentMeta, ComponentStory } from "@storybook/react"

import { MyNewButton } from "./MyNewButton"

export default {
  title: "MyComponents/MyNewButton",
  component: MyNewButton,
} as ComponentMeta<typeof MyNewButton>

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof MyNewButton> = (args) => (
  <MyNewButton {...args} />
)

export const First = Template.bind({})
First.args = {
  label: "MyNewButton",
  backgroundColor: "red",
}
```

and Here is the storybook screenshot. [image]

Answer (score 1):

So, I can see you are overlooking some basic steps and I'm going to point them out to you. Your Storybook is rendering fine.

First, you are rendering a button from MUI without a label/text. You are supposed to have an opening tag and a closing tag for the button.
so, it should be `<Button>Hello World!</Button>` and not `<Button />`.

After fixing that, the next step is to use your args in your MyNewButton component so that storybook will know what to change your background color to.

```
import { FC } from "react";

type ButtonProps = {
 backgroundColor: string;
 label: string;
};

export const MyNewButton: FC<ButtonProps> = (props) => {
 const { backgroundColor, label } = props;

 const style = {
   backgroundColor,
 };
 return (
   <Button variant="contained" style={style}>
     {label}
   </Button>
 );
};
```

Your button should be rendering fine correctly now and to make change the background in your app, you just have to pass in the props like so:

```
<MyNewButton backgroundColor={"green"} label={"My New Button"} />
```

Comment: Your first example shows many errors , like duplicating and I have managed to display Button with something like this `<Button>{label}</Button>` But I can't pass any props to that button. I can change for example button variant  in this way `<Button variant="contained">{label}</Button>`  . But couldn't find a way how to pass those attributes in props instead of using them straightforward like that. Thanks in advance man. If you help me through this you will be lifesaver.

Comment: @Nika It just clicked that you are working with typescript and I'm sorry I overlooked that. For you to be able to use them as props, you have to define them first and i just edited my response. What I did what to create a ButtonProps and used it. Also, in your app.js file, I deleted the color props because it was not used defined anywhere. You can leave it if you want but remember to add it to the button pops type and use it in the button component. I hope this solves the problem.